# If based on specific values in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a pandas dataframe such as this :

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df['reject'] = ['RHO','AHO','AHO','RHO','RHO']

          A         B         C reject
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738    RHO
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278    AHO
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219    AHO
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274    RHO
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863    RHO
```

And i'd like to compute based on last row of the last column.
I try it doing so :

```
if 'AHO' in df.iloc[-1:,-1:]:
   print('AH0')
elif 'RHO' in df.iloc[-1:,-1:]:
   print('RH0')
```

But my conditions does not match any of the values of the last cell of my dataframe.
I think that i do not have the right way to select this cell but can not find the proper way.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `slice`

```py
if 'AHO' in df.iloc[-1,-1]:
   print('AH0')
elif 'RHO' in df.iloc[-1,-1]:
   print('RH0')
```